# Hadoop Serialization on HashMap and float[]

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization

Currently, I am working on converting normal Java code into `MapReduce` structure on `Hadoop`.

I want to modify the class `Graph` like below, I still have no idea of how to serialize and deserialize the `HashMap` and `float[]` type. The part of code is below.

Code:

```
public class Graph implements WritableComparable, Cloneable {
  private static long serialVersionUID = 3L;
  public static int MAX_FREQUENCY = 3;
  public static float[] freqWeight = { 1.0F, 1.6F, 2.0F };
  int nNodes;
  int nEdges;
  String strName;
  HashMap<String, Node> nodes;
  boolean isMCS;
  String taxonomyName;


@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    out.writeBoolean(isMCS);
    out.writeInt(nEdges);
    out.writeInt(nNodes);
    out.writeLong(serialVersionUID);
    out.writeInt(MAX_FREQUENCY);
    out.writeBytes(strName);
    out.writeBytes(taxonomyName);
    //ArrayWritable a=new ArrayWritable(FloatWritable.class);

    //HashMap
    //float[]
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    isMCS=in.readBoolean();
    nEdges=in.readInt();
    nNodes=in.readInt();
    serialVersionUID=in.readLong();
    MAX_FREQUENCY=in.readInt();
    strName=in.readLine();
    taxonomyName=in.readLine();

    //HashMap
    //float[]
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Graph graph) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

.........
```

Comment: Can you indent the code so it is readable?

Comment: Sorry it is my first time to use Stackoverflow. I got what u mean. I can read it in my computer, only the variables related lines are not indented. But the code is still readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ArrayPrimitiveWritable:

```
// float[] floats
new ArrayPrimitiveWritable(floats).write(out);


ArrayPrimitiveWritable apw = (float[]) new ArrayPrimitiveWritable().readFields(in);
float[] floats = (float[]) apw.get();
```

Use MapWritable for the map.  MapWritable basically is a map where the key and value types are both Writables.  Like ArrayPrimiveWriatable, MapWritable implements readFiles() and write() methods for serialization.

Comment: Thanks. It really works on write, but for input it still doesn't work. It says that there is no readFiles() funtion and I used readField() instead but it says can not cast from void to float[]. Thank you so much. And how to write the CompareTo() function in this case?

Comment: That's a typo on my part... sorry.  Fixed my answer